# Solving a Tricky Integral on Python

Tags: python, integration, trigonometry

I'm currently working on solving a solid angle calculation for my physics project. My python skills are basic and I need some hints/tips on how to go about solving this equation which I obtained from a research paper - equation 9b on (http://ac.els-cdn.com/S0969804306002090/1-s2.0-S0969804306002090-main.pdf?_tid=7b61d61e-d162-11e4-9032-00000aab0f6c&acdnat=1427118343_91eaa37dbd9242927e86c41952074750)

The integral is:

arccos[p^2 + r^2 + h^2 * tan(x) / 2 p h tan(x)] * sin(x)dx

with h = 68, r = 24.8 and p = 40.2

from x = 12.76 degrees to  x = 43.71 degrees.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: This is not a question for stack overflow, try [Math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0):

There is a built in function `math` which should be imported like this:

```
>>> import math
```

`math.acos()` is arcos and `**` is exponentiation.There is also `math.tan()` and `math.sin()`.You could use `dir(math)` find more functions in the math module.Use the `help()` function to see its uses.
Try to carry on with this.It would be fun.

Comment: thanks, but I got it sorted with the help of Math.SE

Comment: @Pete If you could say how you solved it, it would be greatly helpful

Comment: I'll link you to felipeh's answer on the math.se page:

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1204247/solid-angle-integrals/1204343#1204343

Comment: @Pete Thanks.Numpy is always quicker than the normal python calculation.Mark Lutz said about it on his book, 'Learning Python'